# Can I convert My Struts based web application into maven project that project is too large and most of dependency is not available

Tags: maven, struts2

I want to convert my Struts based dynamic web application into maven application that project is large I have added all Maven dependency even though it is creating problems like class not found exception class is available in maven dependency

I want to convert my large old web app into maven now

Comment: There’s no way to help with the information provided.

Comment: What is your question? Maven has a dependency management provided by the public repository. The class not found exception occured when some classes can't be loaded because they are not available on classpath. Without details it's impossible to answer you question. This question should include more details and clarify the problem. If you need more help read this [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

It is always possible to do that. First create your `pom.xml` and add all libs which can be downloaded from maven. ( `struts` and many other frameworks and libraries are in maven repo)

If you face jars which are not already in maven, then you there are some workarounds for it eg: [How to add local jar files to a Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project/22300875#22300875)

After that you must configure your build tool to use Maven, ex: if you are using eclipse, you must convert your project in to maven project.